# How to find the file downloaded by web browser in Android

Tags: android

I am using this code to download a file from my Activity. It downloads the file correctly on emulator and shows the downloading in notification too. But when i click on notification it just goes off.

```
String url = "http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityLifecycle.zip";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri u = Uri.parse(url);
                intent.setData(u);
                startActivity(intent);
```

I need to store the path of this downloaded file.

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: downloading from browser is your requirements ?

Comment: I am already downloading from browser.

Comment: i mean that you want to download pro grammatically yourself or want to pass the intent alone ? you can use async task to download the file from your app itself/

Answer (score 1):

I think the locations of files downloaded by web browser is left to web browser discretion (no obligation to publish it). So I think the best you can do is changing your strategy :

- first download the file. This question explain how to do it : [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)
- then launch your ACTION_VIEW intent, but pass the uri of the just downloaded file instead of the external url